# É possível usar conexões Websocket em Apache?

Tags: apache, socket, websocket, tcp

Com o surgimento dos [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets) nos navegadores, surgiu-me também o interesse de fazer algumas implementações em algumas aplicações. É claro que com a ideia vem as dúvidas iniciais.

Uma das dúvidas que me surgiram é sobre o Apache. Tradicionalmente utilizo PHP e Apache para desenvolver aplicações Web.

Quando se usa Websocket, geralmente os tutoriais ensinam você utilizar um script que abre uma conexão TCP em uma determinada porta. Então, você usa o  JavaScript para se conectar a essa porta.

Ao invés de criar um script independente no servidor para rodar esse Websocket, eu poderia utilizar o Apache? Porque eu notei que o Websocket usa uma resposta com o status `101` e alguns headers específicos, o que seria perfeitamente possível retornar via Apache. Porém, tenho dúvidas sobre o Apache possuir recursos para suportar Websocket.

Vi essa pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334320/using-websocket-on-apache-server) sobre o assunto e tive a impressão que o Apache não seria indicado. Se não é realmente indicado, qual é o motivo?

Quais seriam as ferramentas/recursos mais indicadas para começar a se trabalhar com Websocket, caso o Apache não sirva para tal finalidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe o [`mod_proxy_wstunnel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) (requer Apache 2.4.5 e também ter instalado e ativado o [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html))

Basicamente no seu `.conf` (depende do sistema, no windows geralmente fica a maioria no `httpd.conf`) remova os comentários das seguintes linhas:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

Em distribuições baseadas em Ubuntu deve usar:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

Em Debian:

```
su && a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

Mas sobre distros isso é algo que não dá para abordar porque cada uma tem seu próprio meio de gerenciar isso, algumas tem que instalar recursos de terceiros, então a resposta ficaria muito extensa.

Vale lembrar que o `ProxyPass` não funciona em `.htaccess` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Então basicamente em um VHost ou Directory você pode adicionar o proxypass para a sua "aplicação websocket", por exemplo (para acesso de HTTP ou HTTPS:

```
ProxyPass "/ws2/" "ws://localhost:9001/"
```

Se for para acesso com HTTPS:

```
ProxyPass "/wss2/" "ws://localhost:9001/"
```

O `ws2` e o `wss2` são caminhos "virtuais" para uso, pode dar o nome que desejar.

Nos exemplos iniciei um script node.js que gera um websocket local na porta 9001, então depois acessei o site https://www.websocket.org/echo.html e obtive o resultado:

```
CONNECTED

RECEIVED: something
```

> [image: websocket no Apache com ProxyPass e proxy_wstunnel]

Existem módulos para versões mais antigas do Apache, mas não eram oficiais e geralmente tínhamos que compilar por nós mesmos, sendo Windows isso era um pouco mais problemático, porque tinha que compilar com a mesma versão do compilador usado para compilar o Apache já instalado.

### Servindo HTTP e Websocket na mesma URL

No exemplo anterior o Websocket estará disponível com o caminho de uma pasta, se acessar `http://localhost/ws2/` e `http://localhost/wss2/` irá obter erro 500, no caso poderia "prevenir" o acesso assim exigindo os seguintes **headers de requisição**:

```
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
```

Então usando `RewriteCond` poderá checar se a requisição vem de um Websocket e assim direciona para o "servidor local do WS":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://localhost:9001/$1" [P,L]
```

Nesse caso não precisou configurar `ProxyPass`, creio que internamente isso seja "implícito" (ao menos nos testes que realizei). Vale lembrar que isso também não funcionará em `.htaccess`

Comment: A quem interessar, a configuração para Nginx é bem simples: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html